# Finding the minimum of two dates - PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

PSQL Newbie.. I have a table that has a primary key and two time stamps

```
ID  Start_date  end_date
100 9/4/14 14:53    9/4/14 14:56
100 4/24/13 12:49   4/24/13 14:08
100 9/25/15 11:06   9/25/15 11:14
101 2/7/15 12:05    2/7/15 12:09
101 2/4/13 17:18    Null
102 12/6/12 13:22   NULL
102 12/6/12 13:28   NULL
102 12/6/12 13:36   12/12/12 8:38
```

I want the output to be the minimum of the dates for each ID

```
ID  Start_date  end_date
100 4/24/13 12:49   4/24/13 14:08
101 2/4/13 17:18    Null
102 12/6/12 13:22   NULL
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT distinct ID,
       min(end_date) ,       
       min(Start_date) 
from x 
group by ID.
```

That pulls wrong corresponding values. How do I go about it?

Comment: update your question and add  your result too .

Comment: You want the row with the minimun `START DATE` ? or the minimun  `START DATE` and min `END DATE` for each group?

Comment: Yes , meaning I want the corresponding end date of the minimum start date!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Start_date,
    end_date
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Start_date) AS rn FROM x
) AS t
WHERE rn = 1;
```